# Problem related to trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

We know that $\sin(30^\circ)=1/2$.
Suppose $\sin(x)=a$. Then is there any method to find $x$ if the value of $a$ is given. Please explain with an example.

Comment: Does a calculator count?

Comment: "Any method" is very broad. Of course there are methods. The simplest method is guess, check, refine the guess, repeat until the answer is "close enough." Other methods may get a similar answer with fewer calculations, but they do not get _better_ answers.

Comment: The same can be said for the problem to find the value of $\sin(x)$ if $x$ is an arbitrary number of degrees, for example $1^\circ.$

Comment: Perhaps if you would explain more about what you know and why you ask this question, you might get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we have $$-1\le a\le 1$$ you can use $$x=\arcsin(a)$$

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of approaches, depending on what you mean by "finding $x$".  For example, $\arcsin$ (or $\sin^{-1}$) is the inverse of the sine function so we could write
$$ x = \arcsin(a). $$
Then, using the periodicity (and other properties) of $\sin$, we can write out a whole set of solutions to that equation.  Note that this assumes that $a \in [-1,1]$ (we will continue to make this assumption below).

If you are looking for something numerical, things get a little more complicated.  The sine function is transcendental, which means that (typically) there are not nice, closed form expressions for $\arcsin(a)$ in terms of algebraic quantities (i.e. in terms of radicals).  Thus the best we can do is approximate.

There are many possible approaches, a couple of which are outlined below:

- A fairly elementary approach would be [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method).  Consider the function $f(x) = \sin(x) - a$.  The zeros of $f$ are the solutions to the equation you give.  We know that this function must have a zero in the interval $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.  Indeed, we must have
  $$ f\left( -\frac{\pi}{2} \right) \le 0
  \qquad \text{and}\qquad
  f\left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) \ge 0. $$
  The midpoint of this interval is $0$, so check $f(0)$.  There are three possibilities: (1) $f(0) = 0$ in which case we have found a zero, (2) $f(0) > 0$ in which case there must be a zero between $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0$, or (3) $f(0) < 0$ in which case there must be a zero between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.  At this point, you have estimated the value of $\arcsin(a)$ to about $\pm \frac{\pi}{4} \approx 0.8$.  To get a better approximation, iterate.  You'll get an extra decimal place of precision every 2—3 iterations.
- You could also try [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).  This requires some calculus, but gets decimal approximations much, much faster than bisection.  Start by picking an initial value or guess $x_0$.  The line tangent to $f$ (with $f$ as above) at $x_0$ is
  $$ y - f(x_0) = f'(x_0)(x-x_0). $$
  This line crosses the $x$-axis at a point
  $$ x_1 = x_0 - \frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}, $$
  which will generally turn out to be closer to a zero than $x_0$ (though there are exceptions).  Iterate this process.  That is, set
  $$ x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}. $$
  The values of $x_n$ will very rapidly converge to $a$—under the right circumstances (i.e. assuming that nothing went wrong with your initial guess), you should be able to pick up a couple of digits of precision every iteration.  Of course, hidden here somewhere is the fact that we need to know $sin(x_n)$ and $\cos(x_n)$, which might be a problem (i.e. these also require numerical approximation).
- The $\arcsin$ has a [power series representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series), which can be used to approximate $\arcsin(a)$.  Deriving this series requires some calculus, but once you have your hands on it, you can compute as many terms as you like, and get a pretty good approximation for $\arcsin(a)$.